# confusion about Galera cluster work with spread toolkit

Tags: mysql, galera, spread

I get interested in Galera cluster.
The Galera team claims they have flexible adaptor based design for variety of GCS.

http://galeracluster.com/products/technology/ Their website said "many gcs implementations can be adapted, we have experimented with spread and our in-house implementations: vsbes and gemini"
But I can barely find any resource online about the implementation of combining spread(a distributed toolkit) with Galera cluster.

When I setup a small galera cluster, it can work well. When I updated one Mysql, the other mysqls also got the update.
I am confused why Galera need to work with spread and how to do that.
Anyone has experience with how to implement spread with Galera?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The Galera defined their gcs as gcomm by default, which I think it was developed by Galera. We can define another toolkit as their gcs. The gcs is defined in the part called backend scheme. And then you can implement all functionality via other gcs, let's say Spread.